# Google Analytics - Include Hostname filter issue

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, universal-analytics, web-analytics

I've set a filter to include hostname for a Google Analytics property because I'm tracking multiple domains and sub-domains in the same property. I've done this many times before and it's worked fine. The results should look like this:

```
www.example.com
www.example.com/about
www.blog.example.com
```

But instead some of the pagenames, not all, are coming into the content report like so:

```
www.example.com/example.com
www.example.com/about/example.com/about
www.blog.example.com/blog.example.com
```

For some reason I'm getting the hostname and then it's being repeated after the '/'.

[The image that I've attached shows my settings in GA. These are pretty standard.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hpf7R.jpg)

Comment: Could you possibly have another filter, which is also appending the hostname?

Comment: Nope. The other filters I have set are just to lowercase campaigns, etc.

Comment: Hi @EikePierstorff, the request URI is the page path, is it not? (You've just sown seeds of doubt in my knowledge :-))

Comment: Hi @nyuen, of course it is, I simply messed up.